# How can I gradually animate a canvas closePixelate effect?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

How can I make a rollover animation for canvas effect with [closePixelate](http://desandro.com/resources/close-pixelate/)?  Basically, what is set with a slider here: http://thepixelator.com/. But animated. Do I need to redraw canvas somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each time you want the image to change in an animation you need to erase and redraw the canvas with be pixelation values.